# iOS Segmented controls change text taken from plist file

Tags: ios, controls, plist, uisegmentedcontrol, segments

i have a master detail application where in the detail view there is a text field with some information taken from a plist file store in bundle
in viewdidload i define

```
self.description.text=[self.myobject objectForKey:@"description"];
```

now i would like to put a segmented control so as when user clicks first the "description" will be shown taken from plist
as for second segmented i also have a key in plist file called "medical" with the help of if statement i have made an IBAction for the segmented control

```
- (IBAction)changeText:(id)sender {

if (segmentedControls.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
    description.text=[self.botan objectForKey:@"description"];
}
else if(segmentedControls.selectedSegmentIndex == 1){
    meddescription.text =[self.botan objectForKey:@"medical"];
    }
```

}

have also added the outlet to the.h file

```
IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentedControls;
```

but when i run the app the segmented control  change to the second segment but without changing the text from the plist the key medical that i mentioned earlier
any ideas?

Comment: I've read this question a couple times and I still don't understand what the problem is, Ioannis.

Comment: Could it because of typo "meddescription.text"?

Comment: Michael I have in my detail view a text field that  uses data taken from the plist to display it. Now I would like to add to that view a segmented control so as when u ores second segment to have new data again from plist shown.hope I cleared things out a bit;;;